# Долго работающий скрипт обработки файлов в директории

Tags: файлы, php

Всем привет! Такая проблема: Мне по ftp присылают файлы, Мне нужно после вызова  скрипта  , сканировал папку на наличие файла, если файла нету то продолжать, если получилось то открыть его!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file == "filename.ext") {
            // Файл найден, происходят необходимые действия
            echo "$file";
            $of = fopen($file, "r");
        } 
    }
    closedir($handle); 
}
else {
    // Обработка ошибки открытия папки, если требуется.
}
?>
```

Бесконечный цикл лучше не использовать, это нанесёт сильный удар по производительности, как-то многовато кушать будет и диска и процессора. Лучше использовать Cron, например, каждую минуту, или хотя бы 10 секунд.

Comment: Понимаете мне нужно ждать ответа! Через интерфейс я вбиваю данные, они формируются в файл, и отправляются на другой сервер и ждёт ответа, там он обрабатывается (ответ будет максимум в 20 сек)  и посылает мне, у меня как приходит я далше ввожу данные.

Comment: Можно сделать как написано выше, только через ajax, делаем запрос - нет файла, ждем 10 секунд повторяем, до победного. так и видно что идет ожидание ответа и стопонуть можно и обновить в ручную

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю имя файла заранее не известно.
Тогда как вариант получать все файлы из директории. Для этого можно воспользоваться функцией [glob](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php). Она просканирует папку и вернёт массив файлов.
Далее нужны функции [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fread](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fread.php), [fclose](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php). Они помогут открыть, прочитать и закрыть файл.

Comment: Известно имя файла, мой скрипт посылает запрос (отправляет файл на другой сервер), сохраняя имя файла, и должен потом ждать и не останавливать свою работу, пока  ответ в виде файла не пришёл!